# connect oracle Database using perl

Tags: oracle, perl

I have some problem, i have perl script that connect Oracle database from Perl. it was works fine few weeks ago but now its causing issue i have pasted my code below

```
my $dbh= DBI ->connect("DBI:Oracle:$ENV{'FACTORY_' . $db . '_DB_NAME'}", $db_user, $db_password, {PrintError => 0 });
if ($DBI::err)
{
    print "Error to connect database : $DBI::err \n";

}
```

When i try to run this it's failing with this error

> Error to connect db : ERROR OCIEnvNlsCreate. Check ORACLE_HOME (Linux)
>   env var or PATH (Windows) and or NLS settings, permissions, etc.

i try to connect manually i dont see any issue but here its causing issue. i have give all parameter as defined..

could any one help ?

Thanks
Pandia

Comment: What is the error message from `DBI`?

Comment: AbhiNickz   Error to connect db : ERROR OCIEnvNlsCreate. Check ORACLE_HOME (Linux) env var  or PATH (Windows) and or NLS settings, permissions, etc.!  this is the error

Comment: AbhiNickz could you explain why this is happening now?

Comment: If it used to work but now doesn't then something must have changed. Perhaps you have a new version of a Perl library (DBI or DBD::Oracle) or the Oracle client libraries. If you trace what has changed, you'll find out what the problem is.

Comment: HI Thanks for your reply.. we had server up-gradation today so ORACLE instance not configure properly and now they have configure that now its working fine